# HTML5 shim fallback?

Tags: javascript, html, fallback, shim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML5 in IE6 when JavaScript is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843672/html5-in-ie6-when-javascript-is-disabled)

I've heard a lot of talk about using HTML5 now and just relying on a javascript shim as a fallback for < IE8. But what happens if the user has javascript disabled? It's a tricky situation. Could there be a fallback for the html5 shim fallback? What's your opinion on the matter?

Comment: Not quite duplicate. That question primarily asks what will happen; this question primarily asks what we should do about it.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but I'm mor asking how each developer/designer plans for this, and what they do to solve it really. Basically, I'm trying to start a conversation on best practices, why, and how to implement them. :)

Answer (score 12):

Pretty much, there cannot. The point of the shim is to force IE to recognize HTML5 tags via a hack of sorts, and there is no other way than Javascript to implement that hack. If there were, well, we wouldn't be using Javascript for this.

[One blogger pointed out](http://blog.fakedarren.com/2010/08/using-html5-tags-without-javascript-in-ie/) that you could use conditional comments to change what the tags themselves are if you *really* care that much about your no-Javascript IE users, but I'd recommend against that sort of ugly messing around unless it's for a very significant chunk of your users.

If they're using IE without Javascript, they're just *asking* for a degraded experience all around, really.

Comment: Yeah. It would be a serious pain to implement conditional comments for every tag. Although, maybe you could use conditional comments to display a warning that the page isn't being rendered correctly because of the outdated browser? I wonder how users would react to such a thing.

Comment: @noxxten: that sort of notification seems appropriate. Its implementation would likely be to show it only for IE, and to hide it with Javascript, though that would likely mean that yes-JS IE users would sometimes see the message flash on their screen for a moment before the relevant Javascript is run. That slightly annoying effect might outweigh the advantages for the few no-JS IEers.