# Are any of these method good to use to keep the website compatible in all browser while using HTML 5 elements?

Tags: css, html

Are any of these method good to use to keep the website compatible in all browser while using HTML 5 elements?

**Just for example**

**method 1**

```
<div class="section">
    <section>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p>text</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

**method 2**

```
<section>
    <div class="section">        
            <h1>title</h1>
            <p>text</p>
     </div>
</section>
```

In above method I will not write any CSS for HTML 5 tags so layout will not be disturbed.

**Edit:** my question is specially for Mobile websites because in desktop websites I know I can use HTML 5 Shiv and Modernizer but in mobile still my browser are still in use which don't have support or partial support of JavaScript. and Bandwidth is also an important issue in mobile internet so adding a JavaScript will decrease the performance.

I'm making website for mobile with content management system to update content in future and content will be updated by client using WYSIWYG Editor.

Answer (score 2):

A better way would be to use the HTML5 tags as usual and include the [HTML5 Shim](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/) by Remy Sharp.

Comment: I know this method. But what is Javascript is disabled or not supported in browser? Specially in many mobile browser they are good to render html 4 elements but many mobile browsers doesn't have support of javascript.

Comment: I'm pretty sure no one disables javascript anymore.  I'd be very interested to see the stats on that, but you can safely assume it's less than 1%.

Comment: Take a look at this answer on Stack Overflow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843672/html5-in-ie6-when-javascript-is-disabled.

Comment: @Scott - Here you can see many browsers which don't have javascript support http://johannburkard.de/blog/www/mobile/mobile-browser-statistics-javascript-and-css-on-the-go.html

Comment: @Anupam - yes and @meder suggest the almost same thing which i asked in question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843672/html5-in-ie6-when-javascript-is-disabled/3843694#3843694

Comment: @Jitendra - Those are mobile browsers, but I see what you're saying.  I don't tend to code for the lesser.  I code for the majority in hopes that the lesser get with the program or die off (IE6 I'm looking at you).

Comment: Well in any case, adding HTML5 semantic tags **in addition to** existing divs is silly. It is definitely not semantic markup anymore and you are only making things more difficult for yourself and your users. If you really need to support older browsers, either stay away from HTML5 or serve a separate page for older browsers.

Comment: @Anupam - Then I will have to leave the idea of using HTML 5 because I work with CMS and it's not possible to make two different html code for same website and manage by CMS.

Answer (score 1):

Although semantically both the methods are same, I'd go with **method-1** as it correctly separates **content** from **container**. (*OOCSS principle*)

```
<section>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <p>text</p>
</section>
```

This is the **content**. It represents a `section` of a document and is *meaningful*. You can now enclose this in a **container** (`<div>`) and style it as per your requirements.

*Also, you'd realise that method-1 is more flexible when used in large websites*

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use an HTML reset, use Modernizer to check for features, then shim in things:

```
if( Modernizr.fontface) {}, Modernizr.canvas, Modernizr.audio, etc.
```

This is good: http://bit.ly/b5HV1x

By HTML 5 reset, you can define the tags not understood by browsers:

```
footer { display:block; }
```

Comment: But Javascript support is not good in most of mobile browsers (Old).

Comment: HTML 5 reset doesn't require javascript.  It will make IE 6 look good.  Also, what's most mobile browsers?  Android and iPhone come to mind, which will even show SVG natively.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think either of those methods are any good.  `<section />` should be used for any "section" of the markup that doesn't have a specific tag like `<header />` or `<article />`.  `<div />` should be still used for layout purposes.