# How to make HTML5 work without JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vimeo

I love the design of [Vimeo](https://vimeo.com) and I'm looking at how they wrote the code. Their new design is made in HTML5, but there is no html5shiv.js. Normally I use:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <style>
    .clear {
      zoom: 1;
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

But in Vimeo there is nothing like that. So do they just import this JS code into their main JS ? Or they are using some new method?

Comment: Similar question to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843672/html5-in-ie6-when-javascript-is-disabled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specifically answer your question, they are using an HTML5 shim, it just looks like their `global_combined.min.js` file includes it, basically you go `document.createElement( 'nav' );`.

View: [global_combined.min.js](http://a.vimeocdn.com/js_v6_opt/global_combined.min.js) and search for `header`, that'll take you to the right row, you can see they're doing a `foreach` on the HTML5 elments.